# Using Taylor Series to approximate pi without using arctan?

Tags: taylor-expansion, pi

Whenever I search for ways to approximate pi using Taylor/MacLaurin Series, the example that I always see utilizes the fact that $\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}=1}$. However, I vaguely remember coming across a document that suggested this wasn't the best way due to the very slow convergence. I believe they provided an alternate, quite simple example that didn't utilize arctan at all and also converged much faster. However, I can no longer find the document. Is there such an example? I'm looking for the following properties:

1. Simple equation that uses pi.
2. Doesn't use arctan.
3. Converges quickly.

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Efficient_infinite_series

Comment: Better examples still use arctan and yet converge much faster. Simple, of all things, they are not.

Comment: I thought I saw an example once, but I must have been mistaken. I think I'll stick with the above example, as slow convergence is less of a problem than over-complicated trig identities.